# Use of "Yet" in Context of Older Writings

Tags: grammar, archaicisms

I've been trying to figure out archaic English grammar for a number of uses - an English assignment and an RPG, specifically - and have run into a bit of a speed bump. I am honestly stumped regarding the use of "yet," particularly in the following quotes:

> "Yet a few days, and thee / the all-beholding sun..." - Thanatopsis
>
> "Even if they were to leave Europe,... yet one of the first results of those sympathies for which the daemon thirsted...." - Frankenstein

How exactly is "yet" used in the context of these two quotes?

Comment: _Yet_ and _still_ can be exchanged in these expressions. This is a feature of certain types of 19th century English prose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two quotes use *yet* in different senses.  I would argue that only the first one is archaic, here used in a poetic sense.

> "Yet a few days, and thee
> The all-beholding sun shall see no more
> In all his course; " - Thanatopsis

In this sense, *yet* is used to introduce a time in the future; equivalent to "a few days from now".  But "A few days from now, you'll be dead" just doesn't have the same poetic ring to it!

---

> "Even if they were to leave Europe, and inhabit the deserts of the new world, **yet** one of the first results of those sympathies for which the daemon thirsted would be children, and a race of devils would be propagated upon the earth who might make the very existence of the species of man a condition precarious and full of terror." - Frankenstein

In this sense, *yet* is being used as a conjunction, to mean *nevertheless* or *still*:

> Even if this change was made, yet this other consequence would occur.
>
> Even if this change was made, still this other consequence would occur.
>
> Even if this change was made, nevertheless this other consequence would occur.

[Oxford Dictionaries online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/yet?searchDictCode=all) suggests "but at the same time" as another alternative for the use of *yet* as a conjunction, although it doesn't work as a direct substitute for this (conditional) sense.  I'd argue that for this particular sentence *yet* is the best choice, although *still* is probably replacing it in modern usage.

Comment: I think the statement about the greater prevalence of *still* in your last sentence is correct. However, in the example sentence you provided, a more idiomatic word order would be: "Even if this change was made, this other consequence would **still** occur".

Comment: @ErikKowal That's very true. I was trying to keep it to single-word direct replacements, but the entire sentence structure is somewhat formal, given that "even if" and "yet" both emphasize the same relationship between the two clauses.

Answer (score -1):

You might think about 'yet' as an emphatic particle, emphasizing the plethora of the immediately following noun or noun-phrase. It's perfectly all right to use this 'yet' in modern times. I often use it. When asked to describe my travels in southeast Asia (many years) I often break into Old English. '...Yet another white man doomed to rot under the tropic sun!' (one more of the many white men who became doomed under the tropic sun)--It gives the narration a Maugham-like quality.